# Why can't I display contents of file the second time plus jump of lines after counting the total number of lines in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java.I am stuck in this code.I have two questions.
        1:Why my second while statement doesn't run at all?
        2:In my first while statement,if i have both statements,it gives me wrong answer.It halves the lenght of my file.While with only one statement,no matter which,the answer is correct.Can anyone explain it to me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class HangMan {
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
        System.out.println("This is like Hangman(type) game for movies");
        System.out.println("You have 10 guesses to make");
        File file = new File("movielist.txt");
        Scanner filescanner = new Scanner(file);
        int count = 0;
        while (filescanner.hasNextLine()){
                System.out.println(filescanner.nextLine());
            count += filescanner.nextLine().split("/n").length;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        while (filescanner.hasNextLine()){ 
            /*Why it's not being run at all?*/
            System.out.println(filescanner.nextLine());
            System.out.println("hi");
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: the first loop made the scanner reach till the end of file.. there is no more nextLines. You need to create a new scanner for the second loop. or do scanner.reset()

Comment: Why do you even need a second loop at all?  The code already outputs the contents of the file followed by the count.

Comment: Does this even compile?  It looks like you've got a whole lot of code that's outside your class.  Any code that you want to run needs to be within a method of your class (or a static initialiser block - but that's something you'll learn about later).

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I am pretty certain that was just to put emphasis on which code does not run, corrected that.

Comment: @luk2302 Oh I see now.  Well _that's_ a horribly confusing way for OP to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you leave the first `while` loop you can be certain `filescanner.hasNextLine()` has returned `false`. That means that the second `while` loop will not be run even once, how could it? You have the same condition in both loops, when one finishes the other will certainly not start.

Your file length is "halfed" because you actually read two lines from the file each iteration. One when writing `System.out.println(filescanner.nextLine())` and a second time when actually counting `count += filescanner.nextLine().split("/n").length`. You should probably do

```
String line = filescanner.nextLine();
System.out.println(line);
count += line.split("/n").length;
```